# How to format system time in C?

Tags: c, time, formatting, strftime, time.h

I'm working on an element of a program that fetches the system time in (24 hour time) hours and minutes, and formats it as HH:MM and stores it in an array. The minutes also have to be incremented by 1. This is my code:

```
 strftime (timeh,10,"%H:",formtime);
 strftime (timem,10,"%M",formtime);
 timem1 = atoi(timem);
 ++timem1;
 itoa(timem1, timem, 10);
 strcpy(time, timeh);
 strcat(time, timem);
```

I tested it by simply having it print out **time**, and this was the output of printf("%s", time):
5. (the time was 1:04 AM)

Individually, the hours print as nothing (at 1:08 AM), and the minutes print correctly.

What can I do to make the array **time** hold the properly formatted HH:MM time?

Thanks for all your suggestions

Answer (score 2):

If I read you question right, you should be able to do it with:

```
formtime->tm_min++; /* Additional checks needed. */
strftime(time, 10, "%H:%M", formtime);
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to adjust the minutes directly and having to worry about wrapping at the hour, you should adjust the time by 60 seconds before splitting it into a struct tm for formatting:

```
time_t now;
time(&now);
now += 60;
strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%H:%M", localtime(&now));
```

Note that calling your array `time` is not a good idea, as that will conflict with the standard function `time` used to get the current time.